# having problems with node:path and Math.floor

Tags: node.js, math, discord.js, node-modules

i cant do Math.floor becouse of this error

> Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'

but i cant install either

i tried reinstalling node
it was not working

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
```

Comment: It should be named just `'path'`

Comment: how do you mean? i didnt required it

Comment: According to the error you're trying to require a module called "node:path"

Answer (score 1):

so i found out that it automatic required node:path if i wrote Math. i just had to delete that line